# Linking CIL with native code

Tags: assemblies, linker, cil

In C++/CLI the following is sample code that links native and managed code within the same file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#pragma unmanaged
__declspec( dllexport ) void func2()
{
    //native code goes here
}
#pragma managed

void func_clr()
{
    func2(); //managed code calls native
}

#pragma unmanaged
__declspec( dllexport ) void func()
{
    func_clr(); //native calls managed
}
#pragma managed
```

I am trying to experiment in getting other languages to link with managed code. I can compile other languages with the available tools and can compile CIL with ilasm. Ilasm produces the final .dll/.exe directly and I cant figure out a way to link in .obj files from other compilers.

Comment: What languages, what obj files, what compilers?

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen MS Vc has those pragmas and /clr compiler switch. I am thinking any language and compilers that have no such thing.

Comment: Did you ever determine a way to do this? I'm looking to do almost exactly the same thing now. Looks like this died off in 09, so this is a bit of a hail mary

Comment: `link.exe` can produce mixed-mode assemblies. However, it would lack the necessary infrastructure to cross-call between managed and unmanaged code.